# Recursive function within Object constructor and TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, recursion, this

Given the following `<img id="f1" src="img/fish1.gif">`, i have created an object constructor as follows ( *narrowed down* the code for demo purposes):

```
$(function(){
  function fish(i){

    this.f = $('#f'+i)[0];
    this.d = '-=1px';

    this.animateFish = function(){
      $(this.f).animate({"left": this.d} ,10, "linear", this.checkCollision);
    }

    this.checkCollision = function(){
      this.animateFish();   //TypeError: this.animateFish is not a function
    }
  }

  var f1 = new fish(1);
  f1.animateFish();
})
```

I am supposed to animate the `img` (#f1 in this case), check for collision and then recall `this.animate` which throws the above error,any fix?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i can't do that, because the "fish" is supposed to move infinitely, i am doing it on purpose.

Comment: Fair enough. I added an answer for you as I thought your error was to do with the title, not the one given in your code comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the callback function of `animate()`, `this` will refer to the element being animated, not the `fish` object. Hence calling `this.animateFish()` gives you a function not found error.

To fix this, store a reference to the `fish` object in a variable in scope of the event handler which you can then use within the event handler. Try this:

```
function fish(i) {
  var _this = this;
  _this.$f = $('#f' + i);
  _this.d = '-=1px';

  _this.animateFish = function() {
    _this.$f.animate({ "left": _this.d }, 10, "linear", _this.checkCollision);
  }

  _this.checkCollision = function() {
    _this.animateFish();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Still trying to fully comprehend the problem though :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help. For more info on variable scope, try this: http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2012/04/javascript-variable-scope-this/

Answer (score 1):

Every time you declare a new `function () {}`, any `this` inside will refer to the newly created context in the function. In your constructor, you have

```
this.animateFish = function(){
  $(this.f).animate({"left": this.d} ,10, "linear", this.checkCollision);
}
```

So the `this.f`, `this.d`, and `this.checkCollision` *inside the function* do not refer to properties on the object you’re constructing, but instead they refer to the new `this` context created by that function.

As Rory McCrossan’s answer says, you *could* make a new variable, `var _this = this` (although I’d prefer `var self = this` but that’s just my style). However, in ES6 you can now use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), which do not have their own `this` context.

```
function fish(i){
  this.f = $('#f'+i)[0];
  this.d = '-=1px';

  this.animateFish = () => {
    $(this.f).animate({"left": this.d} ,10, "linear", this.checkCollision);
  }

  this.checkCollision = () => {
    this.animateFish();
  }
}
```

When you declare a new `() => {}` function, any `this` inside will “inherit”, that is, refer to the same `this` context in which the function was declared. So in my code above, `this.f`, `this.d`, `this.checkCollision`, and `this.animateFish` refer to properties of the newly constructed object, which is what you intended.

Answer (score 1):

It’s best not to define methods of an object inside the constructor, but instead on the prototype. If you define methods in the constructor, then every time a `new fish()` is constructed, it will get its own copy of those methods. Instead, you can save space by assigning the methods to the prototype, so that all the fish instances can share the same methods.

There are two ways to do this. One is using the old ES5 technique, by literally accessing the prototype.

```
function fish(i){
  this.f = $('#f'+i)[0];
  this.d = '-=1px';
}
fish.prototype.animateFish = function () {
    $(this.f).animate({"left": this.d} ,10, "linear", this.checkCollision);
}
fish.prototype.checkCollision = function () {
    this.animateFish();
}
```

That’ll fix the bug in your code at the same time, because the `this` inside each prototype function will indeed refer to the fish instance. For you to fully understand how this code works, you need to have some familiarity with [the prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain), which is why I recommend the technique below—it ‘just works’.

The second technique is to use ES6 classes, if you can support it.

```
class fish {
  constructor(i){
    this.f = $('#f'+i)[0];
    this.d = '-=1px';
  }
  animateFish() {
      $(this.f).animate({"left": this.d} ,10, "linear", this.checkCollision);
  }
  checkCollision() {
      this.animateFish();
  }
}
```

This will also fix your bug, because the `this` inside each method will refer to the fish instance.

Answer (score -1):

First thing, there is an inifinite loop as `animateFish` call `checkCollision` and vice versa.

Secondly, in your animate call yuou have to bind the `this` when calling `checkCollision` otherwise the `this` referred to inside `checkCollision` will be the DOM object.

```
function fish(i) {

    this.f = $('#hlogo');
    this.d = '-=1px';

    this.animateFish = function() {
        $(this.f).animate({
            "left": this.d
        }, 10, "linear", this.checkCollision.call(this));
    }

    this.checkCollision = function() {
        this.animateFish();
        //TypeError: this.animateFish is not a function
    }
}

var f1 = new fish(1);
f1.animateFish();
```